# Nginx: limit_conn vs upstream max_conns (in location context)

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Environment: Nginx 1.14.0 (see [dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/d377983a14b214fcae4b8e34357761282aca788f/stable/alpine/Dockerfile) for more details).

To limit the number of concurrent connections for a specific location
in a server, one can use two methods - [limit_conn (third example for all ips)](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html)
and [upstream max_conns](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).
Is there a difference in the way the two methods works?
Can someone explain or refer to explanation?

example of limiting using upstream max_conns:

```
http {
   upstream foo{
     zone upstream_foo 32m;
     server some-ip:8080 max_conns=100;
   }

   server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /some_path {
       proxy_pass http://foo/some_path;
       return 429;
    }
   }  
}
```

limiting using limit_conn:

```
http {

   limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=perserver:32m;

   server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /some_path {
       proxy_pass http://some-ip:8080/some_path;
       limit_conn perserver 100;
       limit_conn_status 429;
    }
   }  
}
```

Comment: AFAIK in your specific case, it's mostly the same. One difference is max_conns will use status code 502.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`upstream max_conns` is the number of connections from the `nginx` server to an upstream proxy server. `max_conns` is more to make sure backend servers do not get overloaded. Say you have an upstream of 5 servers that `nginx` can send to. Maybe one is underpowered so you limit the total number of connections to it to keep from overloading it.

`limit_conn` is the number of connections to the `nginx` server from a client and is to limit abuse from requests to the `nginx` server. For example you can say for a location that an IP can only have 10 open connections before maxing out.

Comment: "max_conns is more to make sure backend servers do not get overloaded"
this is the functionality I'm looking for. do you know if there is a way to control the error code that returned from max_conns overload? (In my example I think I overwrite nginx's error-code. am i?)

Comment: Also, can you provide links that support it? we also came to this conclusion but we couldn't confirm it via documentation

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page overrides what is shown when an error code happens.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that, if the `max_conns` limit has been reached, the request can be placed in a [queue](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#queue) for further processing, provided that the `queue` (NGINX Plus) directive is also included to set the maximum number of requests that can be simultaneously in the queue:

```
upstream backend {
    server backend1.example.com max_conns=3;
    server backend2.example.com;
    queue 100 timeout=70;
}
```

If the `queue` is filled up with requests or the upstream server cannot be selected during the `timeout` specified by the optional timeout parameter, **or the queue parameter is omitted**, the client receives an error (502).

Comment: Note that `queue` is only available in nginx commercial subscription.